# CORS error while importing a js file in my web based html script in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, vue.js

Im trying to call api from inside vue instance inbuilt methods

But its showing me some error

Im in my training period and this is all new to me

Errors:
Access to script at 
'file:///home/wohlig/Documents/Projects/Training/Rough/Vue/apicalling/app.js' from origin 
'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for 
 protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

GET file:///home/wohlig/Documents/Projects/Training/Rough/Vue/apicalling/app.js 
net::ERR_FAILED

Im trying to retrieve data from my database

```
app.html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>

        </div>
        <script type="module">
         import { nav } from './app.js'

        var vm = new Vue({
                data: {
                    datas:"gsdgsdg"
                },
                created(){
                    nav.getOneId(function (err, data){
                        if(data){
                            console.log("afasfsafasfasf+++++++++="+data)
                        }
                    })
                    console.log("dfafasdfadf")
                }
                })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>



app.js

import axios from "axios";

var adminUrl = "http://localhost:3000/";

export default {
  getOneId: callback => {
    return axios
      .get(adminUrl + "movie/getOneId/5d9d736963a1f027693e7fae", {})
      .then(data => {
        callback(null, data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        callback(err);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This error happens because you open `app.html` directly in the browser. E.g. when you double click and open it.

Instead you have to start a local server in the directory your project is.

If you are using a project template chances are it already has a configured `npm start` command. In this case use that command to start the development server. Otherwise you can go to the folder where `app.html` is and run `npx live-server` - this will serve the current directory. I assume you have nodejs installed (`node -v` to check) otherwise the command won't run

Answer (score 0):

Try using this piece of line in package.json
"proxy": "http://192.165.1.220:28080",

where this host and port will be of walmart and install "http-proxy-middleware" using npm and try again.

CORS: EXPLANATION Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different origin. A web application executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, or port) from its own.Means your localhost is trying to connect other domain so for security purpose it is blocking.you need to enable it for connecting to their IP.

For more clear and wider views :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Also you should be using http protocol rather than  file:///home/wohlig/Documents/Projects/Training/Rough/Vue/apicalling/app.js
Can go through this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp